# Was the outcome of the galactic civil war pre-determined by Dooku and Sidious?

Tags: star-wars

I get that the entire point of the civil war was to install Palpatine as emperor.  However, it feels that could have been accomplished had the separatists won.  Is there any canonical information regarding whether Dooku and Sidiuous pre-planned the ending of the civil war?

Comment: If the Separatists won, the Jedi would have scattered and it would have been impossible to kill them all (or at least not easily). The goal was to position them where they could be all murdered at the same time.

Comment: The goal was to grant enough power of the existing bureaucracy to Palpatine through a crisis and step it up until only Palps is in command and the people feel safer and better with him leading it. Secondary goals were to create a standing army for the people they wouldn't feel threatened by because they were good guys (to start) and to slaughter the Jedi (main Sith goal). Dooku thought he would become Palps' Right Hand man but Palps was gonna have Anakin kill him during Anakin's fall. I am too lazy to go find the evidence right now lol